# Find String Length in Azure Data Factory v2

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm starting off with ADFv2 and am facing an issue while trying to find out the length of a string. Although the portal says `length('abc')` should work, it is actually not working. What is the workaround for this?

PFB error snapshot:
[image]

Comment: Are you using the 'Set Variable' activity? Is the variable type of type Integer?

Comment: @thebernardlim yes I'm using 'Set Variable' activity but the variable is of type 'String'

Comment: either change the variable data type to be `int` or cast the result to a string  `string (length('abc'))`

Comment: Is there any option for creating an 'int' type pipeline variable? I can see only 'Array', 'String' and 'Boolean' @frictionlesspulley

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the variable is of type String, just convert the value to a string using this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#string

```
string(length('abc'))
```

Hope this helped!